# Asynchronous Processing of a List of Objects

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading, mysql-connector

Speed is a serious issue with the project I am working on. It requires a huge amount of IO resourcing, primarily from database queries. I want to know the best way to maximise speed without causing memory issues etc..

Essentially, I have a class called `Model`. Within that model are numerical attributes that are assigned. I then run this model, requiring 10-15 database calls within that `Model` instance.

But I have over 1000 models.

So I create 1000 objects and put them into a list, i.e.

```
model_objs = [Model(i) for i in range(1, 1000)]        // simplistic example
```

I could run it synchronously:

```
for obj in model_objs:
    obj.run()
```

But it is very slow. (~ 5 minutes).

I've been looking at asynchronous implementations that use `ThreadPoolExecutor` but it's causing issues with the database connection, making it hang.

All my queries ae indexed and optimised and obviously my description of the issue is very basic but I don't think its a query optimisation issue.

I could use `multiprocessing` library to harness CPU's (i.e. 2-4) to compress the speed but I think that is not a good solution to the problem.

What is the best way to approach this?

Apologies for not describing in more detail but the work is sensitive and difficult to describe.

Comment: Do you share the database connection between the threads (it's a no-no) or do you create separate database connections?

Comment: Yea I'd obviously not share a single connection with multiple threads. I'd create a pool where number of threads equals max pool size